# Random number in iOS app badge

Tags: ios, react-native, badge

After I install and start my iOS app on device or in the Simulator, the red badge at the corner of the app's icon shows a 5 digits number.

I haven't noticed it for months, then installed some stuff to enable local notifications (linked the standard "PushNotificationsIOS", installed "react-native-push-notifications").

When I saw the bug, I removed everything notifications-related, and yet now I see it no matter how far I go back in my commits history. The number used to change after every notification, but now it is a stable `61'051` after a fresh install.

[image]

I would bet that the device is still sending thousands of notifs from an old bug, and the number is the result of a modulo.

What can cause the badge to show up with such a number? What did not get uninstalled properly?

Otherwise, can I remove the badge altogether?

Comment: check if you are setting badgetNumber in some part of your code using `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber` in swift you can change badge number in react i don't know

Comment: I used to set it to 0 at some point, then removed every mention of PushNotificationsIOS (which allowed to do it).

Comment: pushNotifications changes the badge number of your App even if there is no implementation on client side, check if your push notifications have any value on "badge" key

Comment: These are local notifications, there is no server side. Looks like there is a scheduler still running on my device even after the app is deleted.

Comment: you must send your local notifications all from one and only one part of your code to avoid this problem, check if you are still sending local notifications

Comment: Did you integrate Local notification or Remote notification?

Comment: Local notifications. It is the same lib, but I don't have a backend.

Comment: clean badge using `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0`
and check payload from push notification  badge value

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you scheduled a number of local notifications and would like to get rid of them. Even that you removed all of the notifications related code, it does not mean that already scheduled notification won't be fired. So you have to manually clean them in your code.
If you use `iOS 10+` notifications, this may help you:

```
let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649509-removeallpendingnotificationrequ)